# use auto height with float

Tags: html, css

When use auto height with float its not work but when remove float its work fine. how can fix it ?

there is DIV with auto height (**aboutus**) ,inside it is another div (**aboutus-title p**) with float left but the content is overflow how can all content inside div with auto height ?

http://jsfiddle.net/haeb0q8d/1/

```css
.aboutus {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background: #333333;
}

.aboutus-title div h1{
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding-top: 80px;
 color: #fcd803;
}

.aboutus-title hr {
 margin:  0 auto;
 border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #333;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 60px;
}

.aboutus-detail {
 width: 100%;
}

.aboutus-detail p{
 text-align: center;
 color: #fcd803;
 line-height: 25px;
 font-size: 17px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-left: 30px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutus" id="aboutus">
  <div class="aboutus-title">
    <div><h1>about</h1></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="aboutus-detail">
      <p>
        We are a tight knit team of digital thinkers, designers and<br>
        developers, working together to create fresh, effective projects<br> delivered personally.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear float with `clear: both`.

```css
.aboutus {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #333333;
}
.aboutus-title div h1 {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    color: #fcd803;
}
.aboutus-title hr {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #333;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 60px;
}
.aboutus-detail {
    width: 100%;
}
.aboutus-detail p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fcd803;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    float: left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutus" id="aboutus">
    <div class="aboutus-title">
        <div>
            <h1>about</h1>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="aboutus-detail">
            <p>We are a tight knit team of digital thinkers, designers and
                <br>developers, working together to create fresh, effective projects
                <br>delivered personally.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```